# Query PostgreSQL with Npgsql and Entity Framework using unaccent

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

Is possible to use Npgsql and Entity Framework 6 for query PostgreSQL ignoring accents? In play SQL it's possible to use the unaccent extension and could be indexed with a index also based in unaccent:

```
select * from users where unaccent(name) = unaccent('João')
```

In previous projects using MySql I could solve this problem just using a collation accent insensitive like utf8_swedish_ci but PostgreSQL lacks this kind of solution as far as I know.

Comment: What EF approach do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the **Codefirst** approach, you should try to use **EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions**.

1. First add EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions to your project
2. Add a custom convention with **unaccent** to DbModelBuilder
3. Use it in a query.

Example of database context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext () : base("Context")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        /** Adding unaccent **/           
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CodeFirstStoreFunctions.FunctionsConvention<DatabaseContext>("public"));
    }

    [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "unaccent")]
    public string Unaccent(string value)
    {
        // no need to provide an implementation
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var users = ctx.Users
               .Where(elem => ctx.Unaccent(elem.FirstName) == ctx.Unaccent("João"))
               .ToList();
```

Important notice:
This solution works with **EntityFramework6.Npgsql** (which uses Npgsql 3.*).
It doesn't work with **Npgsql.EntityFramework** (which uses Npgsql 2.*)

Comment: I get, "Specified method is not supported".

Comment: @IanWarburton I need more details about this exception. Can you paste full  stacktrace? What version of EntityFramework, EntityFramework6.Npgsql and Npgsql do you have?

Comment: EF 6, Npgsql 2.2.5. Failing at  Npgsql.SqlGenerators.SqlBaseGenerator.VisitFunction(EdmFunction function, IList`1 args, TypeUsage resultType) with 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException'

Comment: Looking at the source, that method doesn't even seem to handle custom functions.

Comment: I believe it was added in package EntityFramework6.Npgsql so you have to remove Npgsql.EntityFramework and switch to EntityFramework6.Npgsql (which uses Npgsql in version 3.1.*)

Comment: Yes, it works now, although I had to install the latest Npgsql by itself first. I'm not sure why. It couldn't find the requested version before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Net6  this work for me

```
.Where(x => people.ILike(EF.Functions.Unaccent(x.Name)....
```

Comment: Remember to install the extension on the database with "CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;" command, or directly on the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) { builder.HasPostgresExtension("unaccent"); }