# Is it posible to do a select for postgresql using UNACCENT extension IN EF CORE 3.1 with npgsql?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I have read about this for in Npgsql and Entity Framework [Query PostgreSQL with Npgsql and Entity Framework using unaccent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891063/query-postgresql-with-npgsql-and-entity-framework-using-unaccent), BUT Entity Framework CORE.

Is it posible to do a select for postgresql using unaccent extension USING EF CORE 3.1?

How to translate, as example,

> select * from users where unaccent(name) = unaccent('João')

to a .net core 3.1 using EF core and npgsql

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here:
[Query PostgreSQL with Npgsql and Entity Framework using unaccent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891063/query-postgresql-with-npgsql-and-entity-framework-using-unaccent?rq=4)

First register the extension:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("unaccent");
            ...
        }
```

Then you can use the extension using `EF.Functions.Unaccent`:

```
.Where(x => people.ILike(EF.Functions.Unaccent(x.Name)....
```

Comment: A far better solution would be to use an accent-insensitive column collation. Applying functions to fields *prevents* the database from using indexes. Unless you also create an index based on the function expression