# How can I perform a case- and accent- insensitive LIKE (substring) query using PredicateBuilder, EF Core 5, and Postgresql 10+?

Tags: postgresql, case-insensitive, predicatebuilder, ef-core-5.0, accent-insensitive

In SQL Server, it is relatively straight forward to create a case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, `LIKE` query using EF Core 5 and PredicateBuilder.

For example:

- The user is is trying to find a customer in the database using a standard North American keyboard (i.e. accents are kind of a pain to type).
- Searching for `helene` should match `Mme. Hélène Laurendeau`. It is important we can match a *substring* and not just a prefix or suffix.

Assuming we have an entity `Customer` with property `Name`, the following snippet will work as expected:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder
                 .New<Customer>(c => EF.Functions.Collate(c.Name, 
                                                          "Latin1_general_CI_AI")
                                                 .Contains("helen"));

var customers = context.Customers.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

How we can we perform the same query in PostgreSQL (10 or higher)?

We just did a quick (basically 1:1) migration from SQL Server and are trying to update our code to make sure the general migration is possible. This question *does not* take possible query speed issues into account (see links for more info there.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your newly-created Postgres database is UTF8 (which I believe it is by default)

1. Ensure `unaccent` is installed. If not, `CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;`
2. Update your `predicate` as follows:

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder
                  .New<Customer>(c => EF.Functions.ILike(EF.Functions.Unaccent(c.Name),
                                                        "%helen%"));
```

3. Profit! :)

Notes: It *is* possible to collate answers from various questions on SO and other sources to reach this conclusion, but I've been unable to find one place where it makes sense post a comment with this solution that could be easily located. Also, I don't believe that introducing full-text search is the answer to this question, but happy to update it if I'm mistaken.

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/9913) is by far the best and most complete one I've seen and highly encourage people to dig into it when they have time.** If you are trying to move from SQL Server over to Postgres as a prototype, though, this answer should save you a lot of pain and time :)

Some answers have suggested creating an index on a `lowercase` / `unaccent`-ed version of the column but that does not *directly* work since `unaccent` is not `IMMUTABLE`. You can wrap these as required and then index them (examples in links.)

Also, attempting to pass a collation directly via `EF.Functions` (after having created it on the server) does not appear to work either, but perhaps I am something missing about Postgres there.

It *may* be possible to [tweak individual column collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#column-collation).

Some relevant questions include:

- [PostgreSQL accent + case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627951/postgresql-accent-case-insensitive-search)
- [Query PostgreSQL with Npgsql and Entity Framework using unaccent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891063/query-postgresql-with-npgsql-and-entity-framework-using-unaccent)
- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216)

Other sources:

- https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8813
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity
- http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx