# Using postgresql unaccent function in a dynamic linq query

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, system.linq.dynamic

According to: [Query PostgreSQL with Npgsql and Entity Framework using unaccent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891063/query-postgresql-with-npgsql-and-entity-framework-using-unaccent)

I added the NuGet Library and everything works:

```
var result = _context.Table.Where(h => _context.Unaccent(h.Description) == "GARCÍA");
```

But I don't know how to combine it with Dynamic Linq library

```
whereStr = $"{fieldName} == \"{searchString}\"";
```

I tried some things like:

```
whereStr = $"unaccent({nameField}) {searchOpeStr} \"{searchString}\"";
whereStr = $"\"public\".\"unaccent\"({nameField}) {searchOpeStr} \"{searchString}\"";
whereStr = $"Context.Unaccent({nameField}) {searchOpeStr} \"{searchString}\"";
```

But nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are here because you have the same problem, don't have illusions. I bountied this question and nobody answer